# SharePoint online settings pages in Classic mode

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2013, modern-experience, classic-experience

I have a SharePoint online team site that is associated to a Hub.

I migrated content from SharePoint on-prem to it.

The lists, libraries and site pages are opening up fine with modern look and feel. But when I go-to the site settings, the page appears in Classic mode.

I tried adding the cookie "Splnu" to 0 but that didn't work

Is there any other way to change the settings page to switch to Modern experience?

Comment: Can you please attach any screenshot of what do you mean by classic experience of site settings? I believe detailed site settings page in SharePoint online is same as previous versions (classic experience).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Site Settings, List/Library Settings, and more have not been updated with a modern experience.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment above, site settings page in SharePoint online is same as previous versions (classic experience).

Many of the *applications pages* (like below) are still not updated to modern experience in SharePoint Online:

1. Site settings
2. Advanced permissions settings
3. SharePoint Group settings
4. Site collection related settings
5. Search related settings
6. List/Library settings
7. Advanced list/library view settings
8. Site columns & content type settings